# Wordpress: Register existing custom post type?

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, posts

I've been struggling on **using the same categories used on regular posts on custom posts**, so I can query custom posts based on categories too.

Thing is, the custom posts weren't created using `register_post_type` at all, they are created by just using `wp_insert_post` with a different post type, forcingly creating a new type that doesn't support categories at all, so querying with categories has no use. The page is live, so there are a few important custom posts in the database already, without support for categories.

So, if I made a call to `register_post_type` in `init` now (to add categories by adding the `'taxonomies' => array('category')` parameter, would new custom posts be queriable, without destroying the old, existing posts in the database? Or should I try something else entirely?

I've thought about using meta data for the custom posts, but I want to keep integrity between regular and custom's categories.

Thanks for the attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`register_post_type` is mostly used so the post type is displayed in your wp-admin. It will not affect your current database records.

Comment: Agreed. Just think you could add `register_post_type` to you init function. Use the new custom post type. Then remove `register_post_type` from functions.php, all your posts will still exist, if you add `register_post_type` back in, you will see it in the admin again.